# Any good Open Source or Cheap ASP.NET Catalog Applications

Tags: asp.net, catalog

We're looking for a cheap-to-free "off the shelf" ASP.NET catalogue application, that will meet the following requirements:

- Support two kinds of listings:

  - **Suppliers** of Services
  - **Suppliers** of Products, and their **Products**
- Suppliers can be categorised by:

  - Area of specialisation - including sub-categories
  - Location
  - Other data, e.g. where listing came from
- Versioning of supplier/product details
- Easy to use management interface
- Use masterpages so we can drop it into our existing site layout
- Run on a Windows 2003 server, with .NET 3.5 installed

In an ideal world, the following additional requirements might be met:

- Suppliers can manage their own listings

Other products that are available to us (that will obviously need some additional development to meet these requirements) are:

- Content Management System (MS)
- Commerce Server - bear in mind we're not selling the products/suppliers, just listing them
- Simple DB application.

I'm happy to knock something up in MCMS/simple DB, I'm just looking to see if anyone's had any experience with off the shelf apps that could save us some time.

I'm also happy to receive "Don't use this because" type answers.

Comment: did you ever find one, cause i need it to!

Comment: Sadly not, but I also stopped looking for various reasons :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not long after asking this question, the client found a different solution to their problems, so I've stopped looking.

Since then the Web Platform Installer has been launched, and at the time of writing, offered a number of .NET based eCommerce applications including some with paid/supported options:

I've not used or investigated any of these, so your mileage may vary, but I'm listing them here (as a community wiki) to assist the few people who bounce past every now and again looking for an answer:

- [Core Ecommerce Lite](http://www.core-frameworks.com/ecommerce-overview/ecommerce-lite-version)
- [Kartris](http://www.kartris.com/)
- [Kentico CMS for ASP.NET](http://www.kentico.com/home.aspx)
- [mojoPortal](http://www.mojoportal.com/)
- [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/default.aspx)
- [SplendidCRM](http://www.splendidcrm.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Melon ASP.NET Product Catalog](http://meloncomponents.com/Components/ProductCatalog/ProductCatalogOverview.aspx), not sure if they have the Suppliers staff, but easy to integrate and very extendable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - looks like it could be useful for other projects so thanks for the recommendation, but fitting in the suppliers might bend it a little too far :(